# In tcsh how do you get the exit status of a command in backquotes?

Tags: tcsh

I have the following code in my tcsh startup script:

```
set _color_count = `sh -c "tput -T${TERM}-256color colors 2>/dev/null"`
if ($? == 0) then  # check if it was a valid terminal type
    if ($_color_count != 256) then  # sanity-check
        echo "Warning: Color count '$_color_count' for '${TERM}-256color' is not 256"
    endif
    setenv TERM "${TERM}-256color"
endif
```

My problem is that the exit status ($?) is *always* zero, even when the `tput` command returns a non-zero exit status due to an invalid terminal type.  If I don't capture the output of the command, checking the exit status works fine:

```
sh -c "tput -T${TERM}-256color colors 2>/dev/null"
```

How do I determine whether or not the `tput` command returned a non-zero exit status, given it's in backquotes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that this was a behavioral change introduced in tcsh version 6.17.05 (see [original bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=638955)).  It looks like it will be reverted as of tcsh version 6.18.00 (see [regression bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=759132)), but it has obviously made it into the wild.

For affected versions, though, you can set the variable $anyerror before running the command in backquotes:

```
set anyerror
set _color_count = `sh -c "tput -T${TERM}-256color colors 2>/dev/null"`
```

According to my tcsh man page for special shell variable **status**:

> **status**  The status returned by the last command, unless the variable anyerror is set, and any error in a pipeline or a backquote expansion will be propagated (this was the default csh behavior).